# Monotonously increasing injective functions

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, functions

So, I understand that monotonously increasing function ${f}$ is injective because:

Monotone increasing function ${f}$ satisfies:

${\forall x_i,x_{i+1} \in D_f}$, such that ${x_i<x_{i+1} \implies f(x_i)<f(x_{i+1})}$

So then, if for some ${j}$ I choose value ${f(x_j) \in Im(f)}$ and from the definition of monotone increasing function we can say that

${\forall x_{j-1},x_{j+1}\in D_f}$ that satisfy ${x_{j-1}<x_{j}<x_{j+1}\implies f(x_{j-1})<f(x_j)<f(x_{j+1}). (A)}$

If we try the injective function test:

For some ${i,j}$ we have ${f(x_i)=f(x_j)}$. But since the previous result (A) we can say that we neither can find ${x_i \text{ or } x_j}$ such that ${(x_i<x_j \lor x_i>x_j) \land (f(x_i)=f(x_j))}$. So, it follows that ${x_i=x_j}$ and we have proven ${f}$ is injective if it is monotonously increasing.

This proof for monotonously decreasing function ${f}$ is analogical.

But how about the other way around:
If the function ${f}$ is injective can I construct neither monotonously increasing or decreasing function ${f}$?

I was thinking about the plot of the function ${f}$ that looks like a enlarging wave dots but the problem is that if I connect all of these points, I lose injection property. Otherwise, If I do not connect these points, I lose continuous function property.

This is the graph illustrating the idea:

[image: If we connect these points, it reminds of the wave which expands but we could clearly see it no longer would be injective]

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Injection_of_Interval_is_Strictly_Monotone

Comment: Wow, thank you.